# How to generate all datacontract class

Tags: wcf, datacontract, servicecontract

I have build chat service with WCF. I have class that marked as datacontract attribute

```
[DataContract]
public class Message
{
    string   _sender;
    string   _content;
    DateTime _time;

    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public string Sender
    {
        get { return _sender;  }
        set { 
            _sender = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Content
    {
        get { return _content;  }
        set { 
            _content = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return _time;  }
        set { 
            _time = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And my service contract is like below

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="", SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IChatCallback))]
public interface IChat
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Connect(Client client);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true, IsInitiating=false, IsTerminating=true)]
    void Disconnect();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false)]
    void Whisper(string target, string message);
}
```

When i try to generate client code from VisualStudio 2010, class Message is not generated. But it generated when i change the type of parameter "message" in method "Whisper" on my service contract to Message not string.

I change the type of parameter message to "Message" not "string":

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false)]
void Whisper(string target, Message message);
```

I've callback class that require Message class to work correctly.

```
public interface IChatCallback
{
    void RefreshClient(List<Client> clients);
    void ReceiveWhisper(Message message);
    void ReceiveNotifyClientConnect(Client joinedClient);
    void ReceiveNotifyClientDisconnect(Client leaver);
}
```

And the question is why class that marked as datacontract attribute is not generated when they are not included in service contract's method parameter or return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i found the solution.

I forgot to add operationcontract attribute in my callback class.

```
public interface IChatCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void RefreshClient(List<Client> clients);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveWhisper(Message message);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveNotifyClientConnect(Client joinedClient);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveNotifyClientDisconnect(Client leaver);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The service reference only generates classes that are required to use the service. It does *not* generate every single class that is marked as `DataContract`.

> But it generated when i change the type of parameter "message" in method "Whisper" on my service contract to Message not string.

That's exactly how it should work. If the service requires that class, then it will be generated. If it doesn't require that class then it won't be generated.

Comment: I have callback class "IChatCallback" that require class "Message" to be work correctly

Comment: You haven't posted that interface so I can't see what's in it...!